# License Object Trigger not firing on "License Status" change

Tags: trigger, formula-field, record-type, lma

I am trying to write a trigger on the License object (`sfLma__License__c`) in my License Management org.. the purpose of this trigger to make a callout (in a future context) to my service to notify it of any new licenses or updates..

This is my trigger as of now

```
trigger MyLicenseTrigger on sfLma__License__c (after insert, after update) {

    for(sfLma__License__c newLicense: Trigger.newMap.values()) {
        LmoCalloutHelper.reportLicense(newLicense);
    }
}
```

Now if I update any editable field of this license from the UI (for eg. the `Lead` field) the trigger fires.. all good.

But if the managed package which is linked to the LMO is installed or uninstalled, the trigger does NOT fire.

On digging a bit, I see that on install/uninstall, the `License Status` is changed. But `License Status` is a formula field which obviously doesnt fire triggers.

But the formula field is just a `$recordType.Name`, so basically it seems any install/uninstall updates the `Record Type` of a license record.

**So on install/uninstall of a package, if the `Record Type` is updated, why does my trigger not fire?**

Comment: My guess is that triggers are not supported on this object. This is the case for various special Salesforce objects.

Comment: @PhilW if I do an update from the UI (if I change the `Lead` field for instance) it fires
so I don't think thats the issue

Comment: Some operations on Salesforce realm doesn't fire triggers, have you checked the documentation to see if this operation is one of them? If is, I recommend to you create a schedulable flow to verify the record types, create a field like, old record type, store the value in the first run of the flow, after update it when it changes

Answer (score -1):

it does not trigger because recordType.Name is like a change on the parent record, not on the sfLma__License__c record itself.

if you update the recordTypeId of your sfLma__License__c record, the trigger will fire.

But updating the name of the 'parent' recordtype record, will not fire a trigger on the 'child' record, since the 'child' record is still linked to the same 'parent' record (the recordTypeId is the same).

Comment: recordType.Name is NOT what is being changed here.. Its just the value of the formula field. 

lwhen a managed package is uninstalled, the `sfLma__License__c` moves from `Active` -> `Uninstalled` 
That means the recordTypeId of the `sfLma__License__c` object itself is changing here (and hence the formula field will be updated)
since the recordTypeId is changed,  the trigger should have fired right?